# STAD data extraction into Java Application

Tags: abap, saprfc, jco, sap-basis

SAP logs all the transactions executed by user and accumulates them by monthly wise. Information it stores user ID, date, time, transaction executed instance, etc.

Table MONI contains this information. But when I check this table it looks like *raw* data. It's decoded when displayed via the transaction code `STAD`.

I would like to extract STAD data to Java application via BAPI or RFC call.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the keys of the table with the usual `RFC_READ_TABLE`, you can convert the raw data to usable data with FM `IMPORT_DOWNLOAD_FROM_MONI`.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I will try to use the function module IMPORT_DOWNLOAD_FROM_MONI. Great help, really appreciated.